# Python pyodbc sql query could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying take date in python pyodbc module this query:

```
SELECT distinct
regs.[workerID] as ewid_1
,workers.[workerID] as ewid_2
,regs.[deviceId]
,workers.[workerFirstName]
,workers.[workerLastName]
,workers.[workerDomainID]
,workers.[department]
,regs.[applicationVersion]
,regs.[modifyDate]
,regs.[locomotiveNo]
,regs.[deviceNo]
,regs.[manufacturer]
,regs.[model]
,regs.[osSystemName]
,regs.[localDateTime]
,regs.[machineName]
,regs.[ip]
,regs.[simSubscriberID]
,regs.[simRegistration]
,regs.[simIccID]
,regs.[simState]
FROM [PS_SLK].[dbo].[ps_slk_registeredDevices] regs
join [PS_SLK].[dbo].[ps_slk_workers] workers
on regs.[workerID] = workers.[workerID]
where workers.workerDomainID not in ('kolejadmin','02pdawic') and 
regs.modifyDate > '2021-01-01' and workers.workerDomainID is not null and 
regs.workerID is not null
```

Unfortunately I got this error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "regs.workerID" could not be bound. (4104)...

In SSMS everything works and I don't have any warnings.
[PS_SLK].[dbo].[ps_slk_registeredDevices] is instacne is an instance of data base PS_SLK and table [ps_slk_registeredDevices. I try join two tables from this same database.

I searched for some solutions to this, but don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I tried change notation or part with JOIN but didn't work in pyodbc.

Could someone explain what i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `regs.[workerID] is not null` (at the end.) Could it be some case sensitive/insensitive mismatch?

Comment: Hi Pawel, please update the post with the definition of [PS_SLK].[dbo].[ps_slk_registeredDevices]. Thanks

Comment: @jarlh i tried, and still this same error

Comment: @ekochergin [PS_SLK].[dbo].[ps_slk_registeredDevices] is instacne is an instance of data base PS_SLK and table [ps_slk_registeredDevices

Comment: @PawełDawicki I meant post please the definition of ps_slk_registeredDevices

Comment: @ekochergin yes, i update it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working. I needed to restart venv.